# Blowing the stack on purpose with CompletableFuture yielded no stack overflow?

Tags: java, completable-future

I am trying to see the behavior on purposefully causing a stack overflow with CompletableFuture but instead found out, it resulted in success and my recursive loop just stopped and exited and junit test passed. This is really not the behavior I would want. I would want a fail fast behavior so I know to fix my code.

```
@Test
public void testBlowTheStack() throws InterruptedException {
    recurse(0);

    System.out.println("done");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}


private void recurse(int counter) {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> future = writeData(counter);
    future.thenAccept(p -> recurse(p+1));       
}

private CompletableFuture<Integer> writeData(int counter) {
    System.out.println("counter="+counter);
    if(counter == 1455) {
        System.out.println("mark");
    }

    CompletableFuture<Integer> future = new CompletableFuture<Integer>();
    future.complete(counter);
    return future;
}
```

I tried to debug in eclipse around count 1455 but eclipse freezes and can't load the stack trace so I could not find the reason behind this behavior.

So my questions are simple

1. Is my code somehow incorrect?
2. how is the CompletableFuture exiting successfully (or perhaps it isn't in which case how is my junit test case passing).

Maybe OS matters...I am on a mac.  I previously had my own home grown promises and those successfully blow the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thenAccept` takes a `Consumer` and returns a `CompletableFuture<Void>`. If the consumer returns normally without exception, the void future is completed with null. If the consumer throws an exception the future is completed exceptionally with that exception.

If you want to catch the `StackOverflowException` you need to get it from the returned future. There are many ways to do that. For example:

```
future.thenAccept(p -> recurse(p+1)).join();
```

or

```
future.thenAccept(p -> recurse(p+1))
      .exceptionally(e -> {
          e.printStackTrace();
          return null;
      });
```

Comment: ah, of course...that makes sense as the exception would be caught....cool, that is more what I expected.

Comment: hmmm, I will have to test stackoverflow and then calling exceptionlly method (and force stack overflow there)..I wonder how that is handled.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but my interpretation of the Java API documentation is that the second exception would be lost and the future would complete with the original exception. In other words, if `exceptionally` throws an exception it's a noop.